# RestAssured adding item to List POJO

Tags: list, rest-assured

I am trying to use this following JSON file as input :

```
{
    "partnerID": "529",
    "requests": [
        {
            "agencyId": "461007",   
            "lobCd": "LM"
        },
        {
            "agencyId": "023000",  
            "lobCd": "LM"
        },
        {
            "agencyId": "103000",  
            "lobCd": "GL"
        },
        {
            "agencyId": "023000",  
            "lobCd": "GL"
        }
    ]
}
```

These are my 2 POJO files :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Root {

    public String partnerID;
    public List<Request> requests;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Request {

    public String agencyId;
    public String lobCd;
}
```

Request Body

```
public class SuccessfulRequestBody {

    public Object getLobSycbBody_Successful() {

        Root root = new Root();
        Request request = new Request();

        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        root.setPartnerID("529");


        request.setAgencyId("461007");
        request.setLobCd("LM");
        requests.add(request);
        root.setRequests(requests);

        requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        request.setAgencyId("023000");
        request.setLobCd("LM");
        requests.add(request);
        root.setRequests(requests);

        requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        request.setAgencyId("103000");
        request.setLobCd("GL");
        requests.add(request);
        root.setRequests(requests);

        requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        request.setAgencyId("103000");
        request.setLobCd("GL");
        requests.add(request);
        root.setRequests(requests);

        requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        request.setAgencyId("023000");
        request.setLobCd("GL");
        requests.add(request);

        root.setRequests(requests);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Problem : When I run the test I only get the last agency 023000, the others are not getting added to the list. I wanted to see all the other agencies, lob in my output file.

```
    @Test
    public void getSuccessResponse(){

        String token= generateToken.getGenerateToken();
        SuccessfulRequestBody successfulRequestBody = new SuccessfulRequestBody();

        Response response = given().log().all().contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8").
                contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8").
                header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                header("Authorization", "Bearer "+token).
                //baseUri("https://test-cerebria.test.homesitecommercial.kitchen/api/msaivanspolicyservice/agent/lobSync").
                body(successfulRequestBody.getLobSycbBody_Successful()).
                        when().
                        post("https://test-cerebria.test.homesitecommercial.kitchen/api/msaivanspolicyservice/agent/lobSync").
                        then().
                        extract().response();

    }
}
```

Output :

```
{
    "partnerID": "529",
    "requests": [
        {
            "agencyId": "023000",
            "lobCd": "GL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach would be to create multiple objects for the class `request`, set the values and add them to a `list`

```
Root root = new Root();
Request request1 = new Request();
Request request2 = new Request();
Request request3 = new Request();
Request request4 = new Request();

request1.setAgencyId("461007");
request1.setLobCd("LM");

request2.setAgencyId("023000");
request2.setLobCd("LM");

request3.setAgencyId("103000");
request3.setLobCd("GL");

request4.setAgencyId("023000");
request4.setLobCd("GL");

List<Request> list = new LinkedList<Request>();
list.add(request1);
list.add(request2);
list.add(request3);
list.add(request4);

root.setPartnerID("529");
root.setRequests(list);
```